# How can iterate throught a dictionary in a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is an output from traversing through different folders in a directory:

`r= [{'s.data': [22, 10, 21, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 'd.data': [1, 5, 3,67,8,4, 9, 0, 2], 'q.data': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 32], 't.data': [32, 21, 9, 2, 13, 5, 4, 9, 7], 'k.data': [3, 7, 2, 5, 68, 90, 23, 11, 22]}, {'s.data': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 'd.data': [2, 6, 3, 8, 9, 0, 3, 2, 5], 'q.data': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 't.data': [0, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3], 'k.data': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]}, {'s.data': [4, 3, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9], 'd.data': [6, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], 'q.data': [23, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5, 0, 8], 't.data': [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 11, 2, 6, 7], 'k.data': [1, 0, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7, 4]}, {'s.data': [1, 9, 7, 0, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5], 'd.data': [4, 3, 7, 9, 2, 3, 0, 9, 10], 'q.data': [0, 23, 4, 2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 0], 't.data': [4, 1, 7, 4, 0, 8, 9, 9, 0], 'k.data': [9, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]}, {'s.data': [22, 10, 21, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 'd.data': [5, 7, 4, 5, 8, 9, 0, 2, 3], 'q.data': [3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1], 't.data': [2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0], 'k.data': [3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 2]}]`

How can I print only the values like the following without the keys as follows:

`[[22, 10, 21, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 
[4, 3, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9],
[1, 9, 7, 0, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5]]`

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your post and format it for improved legibility: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Do you need any specific order over the keys (`s.data`, `d.data`, etc...) or want to show only some specific one?

Comment: You have 5 dictionaries in your list, but just 4 lists in the required output...  Do you need to skip over repeated data (the last "s" data being equal to the first one)?

Comment: I do need order over the keys but, what I want is to have s.data from the five dictionary in to one list and the d.data in to one list , q.data in to one list and so on. Generally having the first item in the dictionary to one group and the second item to one group and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, if you don't need a specific ordering across the `s.data`, `k.data`, etc keys.

```
 print [x.values() for x in r]
```

Alternativelym if you care only about `s.data` or any other specific key, you can do

```
k = 's.data'
print [x[k] for x in r]
```

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want only the values for the key 's.data' in each of the dictionaries. You can do that as follows:

```
[d['s.data'] for d in r]
```